# Mean Parametrization of Bernoulli Distribution(Exponential Family)

Tags: probability, distributions, exponential-family

In class, we defined an exponential family to be of distributions with density of form

$$h(x) \exp(\langle\theta, T(x)\rangle-A(\theta))$$

$\langle~,~\rangle$ is the inner product and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is the parameter. For our purpose, this can be treated as a dot product between two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

We also learned that for a regular exponential family, the gradient of $A(\theta)$ is one-to-one map from the canonical parameter space (the set of $\theta$ such that the integral $\int h(x) \exp(\langle\theta, T(x)\rangle) dx < \infty$) into $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Since it's one-to-one, we should be able to use gradient of $A(\theta)$, which is $E_\theta(T(X))$ as parameters.  This is what we call mean parametrization.

Now, consider the Bernoulli distribution with success probability $p$, which has a minimal representation $\exp(x \theta - A(\theta))$ with $\theta = \log \frac{p}{1-p}$, and $A(\theta) = \log(1+e^\theta)$, with $x=0,1$.

We know that $E_{\theta}(X) = p$. So what's the mean parametrization?

For example, we can try $\exp(\log(1-p) I_{x=0} + \log(p)I_{x=1})$, but the parameters are $\log(1-p), \log(p)$, instead of just $p$.

It seems like no matter what, there will be $\log$ involved with $p$, so how can we parameterize the Bernoulli distribution with respect to $p$ with the distribution still being an exponential family?

Comment: I'm not clear where you're stuck.  The natural parameter for the Bernoulli is in fact $\theta = \log p/(1-p)$, and the logit transform, which can be found by differentiating $A(\theta)$, allows you to transform the natural parameter back into $p$.  So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @jbowman basically, it seems like to make $p$ the new parameter, we should have $\exp(<p, T(x)-A(p))$. I took that to mean reparametrization

Comment: The natural parameter is what it is due to the functional form of the distribution; you can't just change it from $\theta$ to $p$ - or am I missing something?   $p$ isn't the natural parameter...

Comment: @jbowman yeah I mean I think I'm misunderstanding something, but can't you parametrize with $t(x) = (I_{x=0}, I_{x=1}) and $(\log (1-p), \log(p))$ for example?

Comment: @jbowman or with normal distribution, the mean parametrization is $(\mu, -\frac{1}{2}(\mu^2+\sigma^2)$, so I assumed there was a way to parametrize the normal distribution with  $(\mu, -\frac{1}{2}(\mu^2+\sigma^2)$ while still writing it as an exponential family.

Comment: I think I've caught up with you now.  You can just substitute the expression $\log p/(1-p)$ for $\theta$ if you want; this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#:~:text=Table%20of%20distributions%20%20%20%20Distribution%20,1%20%7Bdisplaystyle%201%7D%20%201%20more%20rows%20 shows you a lot of distributions (including the  Bernoulli) with the natural parameter(s) written out in terms of what we usually use instead of a vector $\bf{\eta}$.

Comment: @jbowman hmm so you can just use function of the $E_\theta(t(x))$? I see that some definitions have \$eta(\theta)$ instead of just $\theta$, but since we defined it as just $\theta$, I was confused as to if I can introduce function of the parameter.

Comment: Their $\eta$ is your $\theta$, and their $\theta$ corresponds to the parameters we are used to, e.g., $p$ in your case.  So $\eta(\theta)$  would be, with your parameterization, $\theta (p) = \log p/(1-p)$.  I think that means you're good to do what you want.